# How to get outerWidth of created paragraph

Tags: jquery, css

I'm struggling to position a dynamically generated paragraph correctly. The issue seems to be, that **$(this).outerWidth** refers to *span.simpleTooltip* and not to the paragraph itself.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', "span.simpleTooltip", function(event) {

$('<p></p>')
    .addClass( "tooltip" )
    .text("foo bar bla")
    .offset({left: $(this).outerWidth()} )
    .appendTo('body')                   
    .fadeIn('slow');        
})
```

Comment: There isn't a width until you've appended it to an element. After all, the width will be determined by the new parent element's width, which could be very large, or very small.

Comment: because `this` refers to the element that triggered the action

Comment: try something like this `$this=$('<p></p>');` and then use `$this` instead of `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var $paragraph = $('<p>').hide().appendTo('body)';
    $paragraph.addClass( "tooltip" ).text("foo bar bla");
    $paragraph.offset({left: $paragraph.outerWidth()} );  
    $paragraph.fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span.simpleTooltip').on('mouseenter', 'document', function(event) {
...
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but the mouseenter didn't fire at all. Thanks anyways.